# How to limit pan gesture area?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I am having my `UIImageView` onto which I am having another `UIView` rectangle. By applying  pan gesture to `UIView` rectangle it gets outside of `UIImageView` also. I don't want to be drag outside of `UIImageView`

I have tried below code but it is not working that way

```
-(void)handleMovementView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint movement;

    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        CGRect rec = recognizer.view.frame;
        CGRect imgvw = self.imgViewCrop.frame;
        if((rec.origin.x >= imgvw.origin.x && (rec.origin.x + rec.size.width <= imgvw.origin.x + imgvw.size.width)))
        {
            CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view.superview];
            movement = translation;
            recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
            [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:recognizer.view.superview];
            [self handleMovementForHandlers:movement];
        }
    }

}
```

If i apply Pan slowly it applies this condition but when i go fast it went outside of ImageView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
-(void)handleMovementView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
CGPoint movement;

if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    CGRect rec = recognizer.view.frame;
    CGRect imgvw = self.imgViewCrop.frame;
    if((rec.origin.x >= imgvw.origin.x && (rec.origin.x + rec.size.width <= imgvw.origin.x + imgvw.size.width)))
    {
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view.superview];
        movement = translation;
        recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
        rec = recognizer.view.frame;

        if( rec.origin.x < imgvw.origin.x )
            rec.origin.x = imgvw.origin.x;

        if( rec.origin.x + rec.size.width > imgvw.origin.x + imgvw.size.width )
            rec.origin.x = imgvw.origin.x + imgvw.size.width - rec.size.width;

        recognizer.view.frame = rec;

        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:recognizer.view.superview];
        [self handleMovementForHandlers:movement];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: if you feel laggy while moving then, try min,max function limit area. For example:             
        var newCenter = CGPoint(x: x + translation.x, y: y + translation.y)
        newCenter.x = min(maxXcenter,newCenter.x)
        newCenter.x = max(minXCenter,newCenter.x)
        newCenter.y = min(maxYCenter,newCenter.y)
        newCenter.y = max(minYCenter,newCenter.y)

Answer (score 9):

Instead of manually computing whether the points are within the view's bounds, use `CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point)`. This is what works for me, and I like it because it's shorter and more readable:

```
func handlePan(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch pan.state {
    case .Began:
        if CGRectContainsPoint(self.pannableView.frame, pan.locationInView(self.pannableView)) {
            // Gesture started inside the pannable view. Do your thing.
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Matt Quiros' answer, and in **Swift 3 / 4**:

```
func shouldRespondToGesture(_ gesture: UIGestureRecognizer, in frame: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return gesture.state == .began && frame.contains(gesture.location(in: self.view))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the coordinate (CGRect) of recognizer(Pan Gesture recognizer) then get coordinate (CGRect) of ImageView(Your ImageView).

And then compare this coordinate according to your requirement.

If you are still facing any problem then log the x and y value of image view and recognizer.

Comment: Please do not beg in an answer for 'likes'.