# How to limit the area in which an object can be moved to the boundaries of another view with pan gestures?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to restrict the area a UITextView can be moved to only the frame of another view. I tried to accomplish this with the following code, however, it will not properly restrict where the user can drag the UITextView:

```
@IBOutlet weak var canvas: UIView! 

@IBAction func handleDragOfCaption(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {

        guard let senderView = sender.view else {return}

        let translation = sender.translation(in: sender.view)
        let x = senderView.center.x + translation.x
        let y = senderView.center.y + translation.y
        let point = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

        if canvas.frame.contains(point) {
            senderView.center = point
            sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: senderView)
        }

    }

}
```

See the following image for a visual representation of what I am trying to accomplish. I only want the user to be able to drag the UITextView within the boundaries of the UIView (which is the white square underneath the UITextView). Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Try a little searching - this has been answered many times. Here is just one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47413817/restrict-the-movement-of-subview-inside-superview-bounds/47414810#47414810

Comment: @DonMag, I actually followed what the people said here but no luck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048525/how-to-limit-pan-gesture-area

Comment: What you want to do is also track when the `sender.state == .ended || sender.state == .cancelled` and if the `textView` is outside the bounds do a programmatic translation on the x, y (or both) until it is fully within the bounds.

Comment: @itsfaraaz - is your text view a fixed size? or just fixed-width? and you want to be able to drag it around inside the White Rectangle, *not* on top of the image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is another approach, using constraints...

Give your "draggable view" (your text view, in this case) a Width constraint and disable scrolling (that will allow it to auto-size its height).

Constrain the "draggable view" to Zero on all four sides - then edit those constraints to be `>= 0`. This will prevent the view from being dragged outside its parent view.

**Also** constrain the "draggable view" to Center Horizontally and Vertically - then edit those constraints to have `Priority = 750`. By setting the center constraints to a lower priority than the edge constraints, the centers will only take effect if the edges are fully inside the parent view.

Connect the center constraints to `IBOutlet`s in your view controller, and add `vars` for "current" constant values for the center constraints.

Now add a Pan Gesture Recognizer to the "draggable view".

When you start the pan, save the center constraint constants to the "current" vars.

When you pan, get the translation X and Y (the distance moved from the start of the pan), and update the center constants based on the difference between the start and new values. This will move the "draggable view" to its new position.

When you finish the pan, update the center constants based on the *final* position of the "draggable view".

```
@IBAction func handleDragOfCaption(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    guard let senderView = sender.view else { return }
    guard let parentView = senderView.superview else { return }

    // get the current pan movement - relative to the view (the text view, in this case)
    let translation = sender.translation(in: canvas)

    switch sender.state {
    case .began:
        // save the current Center X and Y constants
        currentCenterXConstant = textViewCenterXConstraint.constant
        currentCenterYConstant = textViewCenterYConstraint.constant
        break

    case .changed:
        // update the Center X and Y constants
        textViewCenterXConstraint.constant = currentCenterXConstant + translation.x
        textViewCenterYConstraint.constant = currentCenterYConstant + translation.y
        break

    case .ended, .cancelled:
        // update the Center X and Y constants based on the final position of the dragged view
        textViewCenterXConstraint.constant = senderView.center.x - parentView.frame.size.width / 2.0
        textViewCenterYConstraint.constant = senderView.center.y - parentView.frame.size.height / 2.0
        break

    default:
        break

    }

}
```

To help with setting up the constraints correctly, I've posted an example project here: https://github.com/DonMag/LimitDrag

Comment: This approach is much cleaner than the others. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: thank you! This answer is what I've used to make draggable view

Comment: This was _incredibly_ helpful -- thank you!